# Difference between NumPy.dot() and ‘*’ in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Normally: `a * b == np.multiply(a, b)`
but in this case :

```
a=np.matrix(([1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]))
b = np.array(([1,2,3]))
print( a.dot(b))
print(np.multiply(a,b))
print(a * b)
```

I have a problem:

```
[[14 14 14]]
[[1 4 9]
 [1 4 9]
 [1 4 9]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FAROUQ\.spyder-py3\untitled0.py", line 28, in <module>
    print(a * b)
ValueError: shapes (3,3) and (1,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

Please, could you explain to me why ?

Comment: * is the matrix multiplication operator for np.matrix, and a is a matrix, not an array. When you call a.__mul__ it does dot product. Change a to an array and it'll behave the way you expect.

Answer (score 1):

#### You should replace np.matrix by np.array to get the same result!

```
a = np.array(([1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]))
b = np.array(([1,2,3]))
print( a.dot(b))
print(np.multiply(a,b))
print(a * b)
```

#### Additional Information

**1. element-wise product**: `a*b` or **element-wise matrix multiplication** `np.multiply(a,b)` **are the same!**

**2. dot product** : `np.dot(a,b) or a.dot(b)`

[image]

#### Examples:

[image]

Comment: we can say this ?
```
with Matrix 
=> dot(A,B) == A*B
=> multiply(A,B) != A*B

with Arrays 
=> dot(A,B)  != A*B  
=> multiply(A,B) == A*B

```

Comment: we can say ? 
``` if A is Matrix and B is Matrix: 
dot(A,B) == AB and multiply(A,B) != AB 
elif A is Array and B is Array: dot(A,B) != AB and multiply(A,B) == AB elif (A is Matrix and B is Array) or (A is Array and B is Matrix): dot(A,B) == AB and multiply(A,B) != AB ```

Comment: Yes I think your conclusion is right since the arrangement of elements using np.array differs from np.matrix and because that the method np.multiply doesn't work properly

Answer (score 0):

`np.dot()` product is the **dot product** or **scaler product** of vectors/matrixes. If you don't know what dot product is I recommend you to learn about it. (Linear Algebra / Calculus).
Algebraically, the dot product is the sum of the products of the corresponding entries of the two sequences of numbers.

For example:

```
a = [3, 2, 4]
b = [5, 7, 6]
np.dot(a, b) = 3 * 5 + 5 * 7 + 4 * 6 = 15 + 14 + 24 = 53
```

`*` in NumPy is the **element-wise** product of two arrays.

For example:

```
a = np.array([3, 2, 4])
b = np.array([5, 7, 6])
a * b = [3 * 5, 2 * 7, 4 * 6] = [15, 14, 24]
```

Comment: thank you, but why i have this probeleme with : print(a * b)
normaly, i should have this result :
[[1 4 9]
 [1 4 9]
 [1 4 9]]

Comment: The result should be like that's true, but that only works if you convert those lists into NumPy arrays with np.array()